# Thunk for recursion inside recursion

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Given a function `m(a, b) = 1` if `n = 0` and `m(a, b) = m(a-q, m(a,b))` otherwise.

I want to use thunk to control the evaluation of this function, and this is what I did. My intention with this solution is to be as clear as possible with the code, especially functional code:

```
let thunk_ite i t e =
  match i with
  | true -> t ()
  | false -> e () ;;

let rec m_thunk a b = 
  thunk_ite 
    (a() = 0) 
    (fun () -> 1) 
    (fun () -> 
       m_thunk 
         ((fun () -> a() - 1)) 
         (fun () -> (m_thunk a b)));;

let m a b = 
  m_thunk (fun () -> a) (fun () -> b);;

m 1 0;;
```

Is this correct?

The given solution was:

```
let rec mthunk a b = 
  let r = a() in 
  match r with 
  | 0 -> (fun () -> 1)
  | _-> mthunk (fun () -> r - 1) (fun ()-> (mthunk a b)());;

let m_bis a b = mthunk (fun ()-> a) (fun () -> b) ();;

m_bis 1 0;;
```

I know it's shorter, but I only did my version so I could follow my thought process.

Comment: Note that `match boolean_expr with true -> true_expr | false -> false_expr` is better written as: `if boolean_expr then true_expr else false_expr`

Comment: From the demonstrated solution, this: `m(a, b) = m(a-q, m(a,b))` looks like it should be `m(a, b) = m(a-1, m(a,b))`

Comment: In the same vein as my first comment, the `match` in the given solution should probably just be `if r = 0 then ... else ...`

Comment: You can test it and find out if it is correct. We don't know your business criteria so we can't tell you if it is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

An important point that you seem to have missed is that calling your `thunk_ite` function on abstraction

```ml
thunk_ite i (fun () -> a) (fun () -> b)
```

is strictly equivalent to writing

```
if i then a else b
```

Thus your `m` function can be rewritten as

```
let rec m_thunk a b = 
  if a() = 0 then 
    1
  else 
    m_thunk 
     (fun () -> a() - 1) 
     (fun () -> m_thunk a b);;
```

which should make the differences between this function and

```
let rec mthunk a b = 
  let r = a() in 
  if r = 0 then 
    (fun () -> 1)
  else
    mthunk (fun () -> r - 1) (fun () -> mthunk a b ());;
```

more obvious.